# How to configure the bitbucket pipeline YAML file to add the selenium chrome image (selenium/standalone-chrome)?

Tags: java, docker, selenium-webdriver, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to run selenium script (Java, Maven & Selenium) in bitbucket pipeline. For this I want to use a image [selenium/standalone-chrome](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome) from docker hub. But I dont know how to configure my bitbucket-pipelines.yml for this. Currently I am using below yml file in my project and I am getting below error on bitbucket pipeline -

**Error**

Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

System info: host: '2469e757-cd7e-46a6-815f-e4e651a95a17-5cdxg', ip: '10.36.149.209', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.0-1035-aws', java.version: '11.0.3'

**Bitbucket YAML file**

```html
image: maven:3.6.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Build and Test
            caches:
              - maven
            script:
            #  - mvn -B verify
              - ls -l /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/chromedriver_win32/
              - mvn test
            after-script:
              # Collect checkstyle results, if any, and convert to Bitbucket Code Insights.
              - pipe: atlassian/checkstyle-report:0.3.0
        - step:
            name: Security Scan
            script:
              # Run a security scan for sensitive data.
              # See more security tools at https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?&category=security
              - pipe: atlassian/git-secrets-scan:0.5.1
                definitions:
                  services:
                    chrome:
                      image: selenium/standalone-chrome
```

**Note**

I am using selenium hub server(http://localhost:4444/wd/hub) to host the selenium/standalone-chrome container and its working fine when I am launching from my local. But giving above error when pipeline is running on bitbucket.